# What's the output of this golang code?

Tags: go, output

My output says

.\main1.go:8: invalid identifier character U+200b

.\main1.go:8: undefined: ​fmt in ​fmt.Print

I even tried it on go playground same response.

Someone posted an answer "0 1 2 3" with the same code.

How come I copied the same code but with the above result.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
x := []string{"i","j","k","l"}
for v := range x {
  ​fmt.Print(v, " ")
  }
fmt.Println()
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/yEdMKKTI7R (tip: always `go fmt` your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are 2 things to note:
first: if you view your source file with simple Hex Viewer, you will see some extra   hex bytes before fmt.Print(v, " "):
20 20 E2 80 8B
lets delete it and now we have:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []string{"i", "j", "k", "l"}
    for v := range x {
        fmt.Print(v, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

now the output is:
0 1 2 3

second:
but normally we use variable names like v for value and var named i for index,
so it seems the code needs attention:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []string{"i", "j", "k", "l"}
    for _, v := range x {
        fmt.Print(v, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

now output is:
i j k l

Answer (score 2):

U+200b is apparently the zero-width space. It probably appeared after a weird copy-paste.

Try to rewrite the code from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you copied it from copied some additional characters, specifically a [unicode zero-dith space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), and put them in between the opening brace in the `for ... range` statement, and the `fmt.Print(...)`. Looking at the paste output in a hex editor reveals this is the case. If you select and delete this character which is prior to the `fmt.Print`, `go fmt` will run again and the program will compile. Deleting all the white space before that statement works, too.

Answer (score 0):

The line 8 of your code has [Zero Width Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) character, which is a non-printable character. This could be in the source you copied from.

Re-writing the line after removing spaces as below works fine.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []string{"i", "j", "k", "l"}
    for v := range x {
        fmt.Print(v, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output:

0 1 2 3

When you run `go fmt` on your code, it says `filename.go:8:5: illegal character U+200B`, which specifies the position of ZWSP.